# How to do code signing with Visual Studio 2022

Tags: .net, code-signing, visual-studio-2022

I am new to code signing and would like to do it using Visual Studio 2022. I got a MS article showing how to do Code Signing [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-sign-application-and-deployment-manifests?view=vs-2022) and was trying to use it. For me, the "Sign the ClickOnce manifests" option is somehow disabled.

When I searched why that is, I came across with [another article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-set-a-security-zone-for-a-clickonce-application?view=vs-2022), but when I follow - "With a project selected in Solution Explorer, on the Project menu click Properties", there is no "Security" tab as what the article suggests.

What I'm trying to sign is a .NET framework .dll. If you know what the issue is or if you know how to sign a .dll or .exe file using Visual Studio 2022, please help me out.

Comment: This probably belongs more to stackoverflow than here